# Quando si deve togliere la "e" finale di un verbo all'infinito?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, apocope

So che a volte si deve scrivere un verbo all'infinito senza la "e" finale. Per esempio, scrivere

> Cerca di calmarti per ***poter*** pensare con chiarezza

invece di

> Cerca di calmarti per ***potere*** pensare con chiarezza.

Non riesco a capire però quale sia la regola a seguire in queste situazioni. Quando si deve togliere la "e" finale di un verbo all'infinito?

Comment: Non è obbligatorio, semplicemente è una questione di fonetica. In certi casi senza la "e" suona meglio. E comunque non riguarda solo l'infinito: siam tornati etc.

Comment: È facoltativo, come detto, ma riguardo ai servili all'infinito, per sensibilità personale, se un servile è da solo non lo tronco mai (volere è potere, il dovere di parlar chiaro), se è normalmente seguito da un altro verbo lo tronco sempre.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Il troncamento del doppio infinito è sempre facoltativo e infatti in alcune regioni è considerato troppo affettato:

> La categoria lessicale in cui il troncamento si presenta più diffusamente è quella del verbo. Tra una forma verbale e la parola successiva il troncamento può verificarsi, purché le due parole siano strutturalmente vicine, e quindi appartengano allo stesso gruppo intonativo. Questo è il caso, ad es., *di parlar chiaro, vuol fare, andiam bene, venivan tutti*. [...] Il fenomeno è invece scarsamente diffuso nelle regioni centromeridionali, in cui compare comunemente solo in espressioni cristallizzate nell’uso, come *vuol dire, si suol dire*, ma è per il resto piuttosto raro e da molti percepito come caratteristica di un parlato ricercato.

Fonte: [Treccani Online](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/troncamento_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/)

Answer (score 1):

È un troncamento "facoltativo", si toglie l'e (e non solo! :)) per far "suonare" la medesima parola di tono più "bello, elegante, musicale, sonoro", tuttavia, non è obbligatorio. :D.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!