# Meaning of "vuol dire"?

Tags: meaning

Google translator says the meaning of the expression `"vuol dire"`

as in

> "Cosa **vuol dire** apologia di reato?"

is `"it means"`.

Is this meaning context specific? I mean, can I always translate `"vuol dire"` as `it means` or sometimes this translation does not fit? Is this some kind of idiom? I'm asking this because the third person form (in the present tense) of `volere` is `vuole`, not `vuol`, so I imagine this is some kind of idiomatic expression...

Comment: Those are actually two different issues. _Vuole_ (in any sense) is in some cases written _vuol_. And _vuole dire_ or _vuol dire_ has often that particular meaning.

Comment: Google? You sent a chill down my spine.

Comment: Nobody gave a literal translation or explained the idiom. Literally, "cosa vuol dire?" means "what does it want to say?", which is an idiomatic way of saying "what does it mean?", as an alternative to the more directly translatable "che significa?". So when the subject is a word or an expression it means "what does it mean". If the subject is a person, or in general something that can talk, it could technically also mean "what does he/she/it want to say", but it sounds a bit weird and unnatural.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look for "volere dire" at [De Mauro's dictionary](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/volere-dire), you will see that this is a common ("CO") verbal expression that can have the following meaning:

> **1** significare: *cosa vuol dire questa parola?*

That is, if you say, as in the above example,

> cosa vuol(e) dire questa parola?

you are asking

> cosa significa questa parola?

a question that could be translated to English as "what does this word mean?".

It's quite usual to say "vuol dire" instead of "vuole dire":  this phenomenon is called *apocope* or *troncamento* (i.e., truncation) and has been treated in previous questions and answers: see, for instance, [Why use the apocopic form “voler (vivere)”?](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8926/). In fact, as you can read in the article  ["troncamento" of Treccani encyclopedia](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/troncamento_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/),

> Il fenomeno è invece scarsamente diffuso nelle regioni centromeridionali, in cui compare comunemente solo in espressioni cristallizzate nell’uso, come *vuol dire*, *si suol dire*, ma è per il resto piuttosto raro e da molti percepito come caratteristica di un parlato ricercato

"vuol dire" is nowadays a crystallized expression, so it's even commonly used in the central-southern regions of Italy, where the "troncamento" phenomenon isn't widespread in usual registers.

Answer (score 0):

> can I always translate "vuol dire" as "it means"

No: often, but not always. There are at least two cases where this does not apply.

Case 1: when the subject is a person, "vuol dire" probably means "he/she wants to say..." or "he/she is trying to say...". Example: a guy wants to speak at a microphone, and some moderator asks: "Che cosa vuol dire?" (What he is going to say?)

Case 2: sometimes the idiomatic phrase "[E] che vuol dire?" means "That has no importance" or "I don't care". Example: I say "Voglio una birra" (I want  a beer) and my wife says "Ne hai già bevuta una" (You had one already). Then, because I really want another beer, I say "E che vuol dire? Ne voglio un'altra" (So what? I want another one).