# Why is the the final "e" missing in "esser"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, apocope

Example from today in La Stampa:

> [...] ma più in generale può **esser** considerato [...]

I get the meaning and obviously it is form of **essere** but I don't know why the **e** is gone.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! [This](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/4083) is a related question, maybe a duplicate.

Comment: @tom: I think your question has really been answered in the page linked in the previous comments. Nevertheless, since answers are in Italian, I'm not sure if you are able to understand them. Are they OK for you or maybe you need some explanation in English?